# Laravel Passport password grant returns Invalid Credentials Exception

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to setup a SPA that consumes a Laravel API protected with Passport.

I started by creating a new Laravel app specifically for this and I then followed the instructions for setting up passport and set up a password grant client.

I can successfully create a new user, save the user to the database, and log the user in. After that, I try to use the newly created user's information along with the password grant clients id and secret to create an access token. At this point I receive the exception.

I read through the log and I saw where the exception was being thrown. Inside `League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant` the `validateUser` method has the following:

```
if ($user instanceof UserEntityInterface === false) {
            $this->getEmitter()->emit(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent::USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, $request));

            throw OAuthServerException::invalidCredentials();
        }
```

Seeing this I implemented the `UserEntityInterface` on my user model and implemented the `getIdentifier` method but I still receive the Exception. I'm really not too sure where to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is some of my code.

Here is my Registration controller:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    private $tokenService;


    public function __construct(AccessTokenService $tokenService)
    {
        //$this->middleware('guest');
        $this->tokenService = $tokenService;
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateWith($this->validator($request->all()));
        Log::debug('Validated');

        $user = $this->create($request->all());
        $this->guard()->login($user);
        $this->tokenService->boot(Auth::user());

        return response()->json($this->tokenService->getNewAccessToken(), 200);
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required'
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

And these are the relevant portions of AccessTokenService:

```
public function getNewAccessToken() {
        $http = new Client();
        $client = \Laravel\Passport\Client::where('id', 6)->first();

        Log::debug($client->getAttribute('secret'));
        Log::debug($this->user->getAttribute('email'));
        Log::debug($this->user->getAuthPassword());

        $response = $http->post('homestead.app/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => 6,
                'client_secret' => $client->getAttribute('secret'),
                'username' => $this->user->getAttribute('email'),
                'password' => $this->user->getAuthPassword(),
                'scope' => '*'
            ]]);
        unset($client);
        $status = $response->getStatusCode();
        $body = $response->getBody();

        Log::debug($body->getContents());
        Log::debug($status);

        switch($status)
        {
            case 200:case 201:
            case 202:
                $tokens = array(
                    "user_id" => $this->user->getAttribute('id'),
                    "access_token" => $body['access_token'],
                    "refresh_token" => $body['refresh_token']
                );
                $output = ["access_token" => $this->storeTokens($tokens), 'status_code' => $status];
                break;
            default:
                $output = ["access_token" => '', 'status_code' => $status];
                break;

        }
        return $output;
    }

    private function storeTokens(array $tokens) {
        UserToken::create([
            "user_id" => $tokens['user_id'],
            "access_token" => bcrypt($tokens['access_token']),
            "refresh_token" => bcrypt($tokens['refresh_token'])
        ]);
        return $tokens['access_token'];
    }
```

Comment: post the exception message you get.

Comment: Are you consuming the api locally? (IE Is the SPA part of the same application?)

Comment: Yes, I am consuming the API locally. I figured out the problem. I was passing the hashed password when requesting the access_token and the PasswordGrant was expecting an unhashed password. All fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the issue. When I was requesting the access token I was passing in the user's email and password but I was passing the hashed password when I needed to pass in the unhashed password.

My request for an access token looked like this:

```
$response = $http->post('homestead.app/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => 6,
                'client_secret' => $client->getAttribute('secret'),
                'username' => $this->user->getAttribute('email'),
                'password' => $this->user->getAuthPassword(), //Here is the problem
                'scope' => '*'
            ]]);
```

By passing the Request to the function using the unhashed password like this solved the problem:

```
$response = $http->post('homestead.app/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => 6,
                'client_secret' => $client->getAttribute('secret'),
                'username' => $request['email'],
                'password' => $request['password'],
                'scope' => '*'
            ]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was magic

when i changed username from email format to simple (alphanumeric only) format it works.
please tell the reason if anyone have for my case.

Thanks