# Change laravel 5.6 default password encryption for passport

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel passport for APIs. I already encrypted my passwords using MySQL PASSWORD() function from another application I am getting the below response while getting token

```
"error": "invalid_credentials",
"message": "The user credentials were incorrect."
```

How can I override the default laravel password encryption?

Comment: it might be duplicate, please follow the below URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036160/laravel-passport-password-grant-returns-invalid-credentials-exception

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: seems you are looking for this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/overwrite-hashing-function

Comment: Not that. I need to use mysql PASSWORD() function for authentication